# What does an executable compiled using C# have?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr, managed

As far as my understanding is,

1. Any code that is written using C# or F# or VB.Net, is compiled by their respective compilers in Visual studio to `IL` code.
2. So, the .NET framework runtime (CLR) installed in client's machine will use this `IL` code to convert to machine code and run the program.

The question is, what does this EXE contain ? IL and some headers ?

Comment: Yes... Details - https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/03/15/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-pe-headers/... you can mostly figure out info by using ILDasm.

Comment: What @AlexeiLevenkov said and also it will have some assembly code which says "Load the CLR"

Comment: Have a look at these:

[What is contained in a PE Header and CLR Header as part of managed Module in .NET executables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633444/what-is-contained-in-a-pe-header-and-clr-header-as-prt-of-managed-module-in-ne?rq=1)

[How does a .net executable run..?](https://dotnetech.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/how-does-a-net-executable-run/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .NET world, those basic units of deployment are called [Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct(v=vs.90).aspx), with an *.exe* extension in the case of an application, or a *.dll* extension in the case
of a library.

In short, an assembly contains four types of things:

1. **[An assembly manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374219(v=vs.85).aspx)** which provides information to the .NET runtime, such as the assembly’s name, version,
   requested permissions, and other assemblies that it references.
2. **[An application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx)** which provides information to the operating system, such as how the assembly should
   be deployed and whether administrative elevation is required.
3. **[Compiled types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466.aspx)**: the compiled IL code and metadata of the types defined within the assembly.
4. and **[Resources](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292)**: other data embedded within the assembly, such as images and localizable text.

Of the above four, only the assembly manifest is mandatory.